# Getting coordinates for regular polygon

Tags: math, bukkit, point-in-polygon

I have an indefinite amount of points on a map based around a center. They should be arranged in a polygon, so their angle is 360/amount of points (http://prntscr.com/8z2w3z). I have a center point, a length and directions so it should be possible to find coordinates for the points. As I'm working with Bukkit to create a minecraft plugin the only way to add locations is to add their coordinates, so I can't simply give them a direction. Here is the code I expected to work, but didn't:

```
        float teamAngle = angle * teamNumber;
        Location spawnPoint = mapCenter;
        float relX = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(teamAngle))*radius;
        float relZ = (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(teamAngle))*radius;
        spawnPoint.add(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), relX, 0, relZ, 0, 0));
```

- `teamAngle` is φ for each point, so with 4 points, it would be 0, 90, 180 and 270
- `radius` is simply a float based on the map size/2 * 0.8. It might not be the best variable name

With 4 points, I'd expect something like this (map width 100 => radius 40, center at (0|0) ):

- A(40|0)
- B(0|-40)
- C(-40|040)
- D(0|40)

EDIT: In fact as a commenter has said, the coords need to be a bit different, i changed it above

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't give any relevant information to help fix your problem.

Comment: Your expected points are for angles 45°, -45°, -135°, 135° with an radius of 56.5. What you should get are (40,0), (0,40), (-40,0), (0,-40). Or (28,28),(-28,28), etc with `teamAngle=angle*(teamNumber+0.5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea behind calculating the coordinates as far as I can tell is correct. I can only guess that the reason you're getting strange coordinates is because you keep editing the same location over and over again (although since you provided only a partial code snippet I can't guarantee that this is so).

The line `Location spawnPoint = mapCenter` does not create a new location, it only creates a reference named `spawnPoint` pointing to `mapCenter`.

The `add` method for locations also does not return a new `Location` instance. Since each vertex of the polygon should be found by adding the x and y components to the center location, you must *copy* or clone the `mapCenter` variable so that you don't edit/change the original center of the map. I'm assuming that you use a loop to create/find each of the vertex locations of the polygon, and without copying the `mapCenter` variable, this would happen:

1st iteration: Angle is 0º, add `40` to the x coordinate of `spawnPoint` (this changes `mapCenter`) and `0` to the z coordinate of `spawnPoint`. Assuming the center of the map was originally at 0, 0, 0, the coordinates are now 40, 0, 0 (this is still correct).

2nd iteration: Angle is 90º, add `0` to the x coordinate of `spawnPoint` and `40` to the z coordinate of `spawnPoint` (once again changing `centerMap`, which we've already edited in the last iteration). Now the coordinates of `mapCenter` are 40, 0, 40, which is incorrect. We should have added the new components to a fresh copy of `mapCenter`.

To fix this use `Location spawnPoint = mapCenter.clone()`. Example code:

```
public static List<Location> getPolygonVertices(float radius, int edges, Location center) {
    List<Location> vertices = new ArrayList<Location>();
    float angleDelta = 360 / edges; // The change in angle measure we use each iteration
    for (int i = 0; i < edges; i++) { // For each vertix we want to find
        float angle = angleDelta * i; // Calculate the angle by multiplying the change (angleDelta) with the number of the edge
        Location corner = center.clone(); // Clone the center of the map
        corner.add(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * radius, 0, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * radius); // Add the x and z components to the copy
        vertices.add(corner);
    }
    return vertices;
}
```

You could use this method like so:

```
List<Location> vertices = getPolygonVertices(40, 4, mapCenter);
```

and it would return the correct locations ([40|0], [0|40], [-40|0], [0|-40]).

Comment: Hello, I was using `Location spawnPoint = mapCenter;` to try to avoid this issue, but understand why it didn't work

Comment: Using `Location spawnPoint = mapCenter` _is_ the issue. You need to clone the variable, otherwise you are changing `mapCenter` itself and not using it as a reference point to the origin.

Comment: Yup, it did work, thanks. Although I changed the floats to doubles because it was really inprecise